# How can i moniter POS application on windows 10 using grafana and send alert when application is down

Tags: windows, grafana, pos

I want to create a grafana dashboard to show the metric of a specific application running on windows 10.

Comment: Your question looks  too broad. Please, narrow it down and show what you have already tried.

Comment: It's not just about POS applications, so why not search for ways and examples to monitor the activity of a particular application on Windows?